# How to perform join in parse database

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a requirement which is as follows.

User will get login and select certain number of sport Clubs around them. After that data will be stored in a separate parse class. Now after storing this sport clubs i want to show people who interested in same sport clubs.

I have created three classes

1)User = All the user information

2)SportClubs = All the sport club information

3)UserSportClub = objectid, UserID :Pointer,sportclubs : Pointer

Now i want keep network calls minimum and fetch all other users who 
 are interested in my selected spotclubs.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UsersSelectedSportClubs")
    query.whereKey("userID", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    // execute the query
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                /* 1) We get the SportclubID */
                let sportclub = object.objectForKey("sportclubID") as? PFObject
                /* 2) Fetch all users from who like this sportclub*/
                println(sportclub)
                    let usersQuery = PFQuery(className: "UsersSelectedHotspots")
                    //usersQuery.whereKey("sportclubID", equalTo: sportclub!)
                    usersQuery.whereKey("userID", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
                /*Getting all users who like this sportclubs.*/
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) ->
                    Void in
                    if let objects = objects {
                        for object in objects {
                           let otherUse = object.objectForKey("userID") as? PFUser
                            println(otherUse)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse is NoSQL database so in it there are no JOIN methods. U could make another table with needed information (example: user | sportsclub | isInterested). Or u could make subquery like

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
query.whereContains("favouriteSportsClub")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the second option and give me some reference link if you have one. Thanks

Comment: check offical parse docs ... https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-relational-queries ... i would need more info about tables in your db to tell you something more specific

Comment: See. There are three tables 1)User 2)sportclubs 3) userssportclubs . Third table is for storing which user is interested in which sportclub. Now I am facing problem when for particular user first i want to fetch all sportclub he is interested in a network call. After getting this data what is the best way to find all the other users who are interested in same sportclub(more than one). (Minimum network  call) . One way i found is store all the sportclub ids in one array and after that use "containedIn" query in which i will provide this array. But i doubt that is this the correct way.

Comment: there is no simpler way than code u posted above ... u can only make one more table with all needed info (user , favsportclub) and then afterwards read from it ... that would be simpler , but with your structure this code above is the optimal way ..

Comment: What you suggest containedIn thing.

Comment: yea but this is for one table ... if u have one table for example with array row filled with favourite clubs could iterate through them with 
let userQuery = PFUser.query();
userQuery?.includeKey("favouriteSportsClub");
userQuery?.whereKey("favouriteSportsClub", equalTo: clubId);
but you are getting info from more than one table so u cant do that ...